# Expo, React Native AsyncStorage not resolving Promise

Tags: react-native, promise, expo

React Native's AsyncStorage is never resolving its promise.  Here's the code :

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';


export default class Session extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('foo');
        debugger; // This hits
        AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(() => {
            console.log('baz');
            debugger; // This never hits
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('catch');
            debugger; // This never hits
        });
        debugger; // This hits
        console.log('bar');
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.props.children}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

The componentDidMount method logs "foo" and "bar" but not "baz" or "catch"

I'm running this on a GenyMotion Android Emulator.

The behavior is the same whether I'm in remote debug mode or not.

Here's my package.json deps:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.2.1",
  "expo": "29.0.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
  "ramda": "^0.25.0",
  "react": "16.3.1",
  "react-connect-context": "^1.1.0",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta5",
"react-navigation": "^2.9.3",
"styled-components": "^3.4.2"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an existing issue with react native. We experienced the same problem a few months ago. Since we were using Expo, we decided to use Expo SecureStore instead of AsyncStorage, and it was fine for our requirements.

More info on the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12830). The title of the issue says that it only happens when remote debugging, but if you look at the comments it happens whether remote debugging or not.